# SQL - Creating a Grouped 'range' set

Tags: sql-server-2005, group-by

I have a table of support tickets - with time opened and time closed. I would like to create a table of ranges, as such:

```
 ticket count   |    time to close 
----------------------------------
        30      |        up to 2 hours
        25      |         2 - 4 hours
        10      |         4 - 6 hours
```

what i have so far gives me the range (using a `CASE` with `DATEDIFF`), but i cant figure out how to group the eventual range.
When trying to `GROUP` on the new `openTimeRange` computed column, the error of course is that its an unknown column.

```
SELECT COUNT([tblTickets].*),  DATEDIFF(hh,[dateOpened],[closeDate]) AS OpenTime

, case when  DATEDIFF(hh,[dateOpened],[closeDate]) between 0 and 2 then '0-2'
     when  DATEDIFF(hh,[dateOpened],[closeDate]) between 3 and 4 then '3-4'
     when  DATEDIFF(hh,[dateOpened],[closeDate]) between 5 and 6 then '4-6'
end as openTimeRange

FROM  [tblTickets]
WHERE closeDate is not null 
GROUP BY  [dateOpened],[closeDate]
```

Using MSSQL 2005 SP4

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, if you try to `GROUP BY` the `openTimeRange` alias column in your original query, you will get an error.  The reason for this is that the `GROUP BY` clause is evaluated *before* the alias is assigned to the result set, and hence you cannot use it.  Using an inline view should do the trick:

```
SELECT T.TicketCount, T.OpenTime, T.openTimeRange
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT([tblTickets].*) AS TicketCount,
        DATEDIFF(hh,[dateOpened],[closeDate]) AS OpenTime,
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(hh,[dateOpened],[closeDate]) BETWEEN 0 AND 2 THEN '0-2'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(hh,[dateOpened],[closeDate]) BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN '3-4'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(hh,[dateOpened],[closeDate]) BETWEEN 5 AND 6 THEN '4-6'
        END AS openTimeRange
    FROM  [tblTickets]
    WHERE closeDate IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY [dateOpened],[closeDate]
) T
GROUP BY T.openTimeRange
```

Comment: Thank you, will give it a go

Comment: Sorry, just had a chance to check now, For some reason i am getting an error `Incorrect syntax near '*'.`

Comment: I just did some tweaking. I don't really need the `COUNT` in the inner view, right? so i just edited your answer to a query that seems to work. thanks again.